# How to focus on currently selected item in Listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview which contains different views as its elements.so whenever the page gets refreshed it focuses on first item of the list.
so  i used following code

```
    listView.setSelection(chat.size()-1);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

now its focussing on last item of the list.
so I want to focus on current item of the list.how can I do it? Please provide me solution as soon as possible.

Comment: You have to set the currently selected items position for that. Like this
`listView.setSelection(currentItemPosition)`.

Answer (score 0):

Before refresh your listview, you should cache follow variables.

```
   // save index and top position  
    int index = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();  
    View v = mList.getChildAt(0);  
    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
```

After refresh listview,restore it

```
  mList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```